# Data Mapping issue NVARCHAR gets converted to INT

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a field in my table that is nvarchar, when being mapped in .Net it gets converted to an Integer (the test has the value '305415042-1')

The Test fails because "When casting from a number, the value must be a number less than infinity"

How can I explicitly cast or convert the field so that it actually takes it as a string and not try to convert it as an int?

The error occurs here on the BetReference (This field will NOT be only numbers, but for the current data i have it is numbers):

```
while (dr.Read())
{
  var b = new Bet
  {
      Id = (int) dr["Id"],
      BetTypeId = (int) dr["BetTypeId"],
      BetAmount = (decimal) dr["BetAmount"],
      BetAmountToWin = (decimal) dr["BetAmountToWin"],
      BetLocationId = (int) dr["BetLocationId"],
      BetReferenceNumber = (dr["BetReferenceNumber"]).ToString()
  };
  data.Add(b);
}
```

thanks

**EDIT**:

Issue was actually due to the datatypes in DB being float, and me trying to convert to decimal. Changed the Datatype for columns and worked.

Comment: Why it gets int in datareader? Do you have typed datareader?

Comment: I have
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
then Loop through with dr.Read()

Comment: @wele Show us the *SELECT*. *NVARCHAR* aren't converted to numbers by little fairies...

Comment: @xanatos
Select * from BET.
The DataTypes from the Table are: Int,Int,Float,Float,Int,nvarchar(128)

Comment: what is your ultimate goal ? you want value as string or int ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV want it to always be string

Comment: @wele I'll say that the problem isn't in the *BetReferenceNumber = (dr["BetReferenceNumber"]).ToString()* row. Try commenting it and see if you still have the error.

Comment: they why are you trying to cast it to int in server side ?? just take it as string then what is the problem ?

Comment: @xanatos you're right i should have debugged it 1 by 1... will try that now.

Comment: @wele *float* in SQL is *double* in C#, not *decimal*... And perhaps you even have *null* values to handle

Comment: @xanatos you're correct with Float in SQL is Double. I changed the Datatype to Money (which after seeing the datatypes, should have been money already). Everything is good now. Thank you.

Comment: @wele And as a suggestion, the next time don't use object initializers with things that can throw exceptions... They make debugging and error-finding more complex. Set each property in one line. So write *b.Id = (int) dr["Id"];* *b.BetTypeId = (int) dr["BetTypeId"];* and so on

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 BetReferenceNumber = (dr["BetReferenceNumber"]).ToString()
```

to be

```
 BetReferenceNumber = dr["BetReferenceNumber"].ToString()
```

Or [ As Suggested by [Arunprasanth KV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4188450/arunprasanth-kv) ]

```
 BetReferenceNumber = Convert.ToString(dr["BetReferenceNumber"])
```

Comment: use Convert.ToString(dr["BetReferenceNumber"]) it will handle null too